# Unit-Root Test Alternative Hypothesis - Dickey-Fuller Test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, time-series, stationary-processes

For a simple autoregressive model satisfying ${p_t = \phi_0 + \phi_1 p_{t-1} +\epsilon_t}$, when you want to test whether the series has a unit root (non-stationary) why is the alternative hypothesis for the test ${|\phi_1| < 1}$, instead of ${|\phi_1| \neq1}$?

The test assumes the error terms are ${Normal(\mu=0, \sigma)}$. Is it because if ${|\phi_1|}$ were ${> 1}$ the time series would explode to infinity rapidly, so we can safely ignore that possiblity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $AR(1)$ equation $p_t = \phi p_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ admits a stationary solution if and only if $|\phi| \neq 1$ (see e.g. Brockwell and Davis *Time Series*, Proposition 3.5.1).

However, in the case $|\phi| > 1$, the stationary solution is future-dependent. Thus, in practice we restrict ourselves to the so-called causal case, i.e. when $|\phi| < 1$. Thus, in this setting, the alternative to non-stationarity (i.e. $|\phi| = 1$) is $|\phi| < 1$.

Comment: When you say future dependent, do you mean when |phi| > 1 we somehow end up with Lags raised to a negative power?

Comment: @JamesBender No, I mean a non-causal solution. For instance if $X_t = \phi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, then you can do a forward recursion to get $X_t = -\sum_{j=1}^\infty \phi^{-j} Z_{t+j}$, so that $X_t$ depends on the future noises.